# Dequeues in Java using arrays + odd and even numbers

Tags: java, arrays, arraydeque

I'm having some trouble with my programming exercise in which I should implement dequeues using arrays.

I already got the operations I need but after the implementation you should run through the numbers 1-20 and insert the even numbers at the end of the dequeue and the odd numbers add the beginning.

After that you should use the method **removeFront** to remove all numbers in the list and should print them on the console.

There is also the hint that the correct output is: (19,17,15...,1,2,4,...,20).

My problem now is that the number 1 is missing in the list and instead it prints out a null value as the first item to be removed.

```
public class Dequeues<E> {

private final int max;
private int head;
private int tail;
private E[] deque;
private int counter;

public Dequeues(int max) {
    this.max = max;
    deque = (E[]) new Object[max];
    this.head = 0;
    this.tail = 0;
    this.counter = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty (){
    return (counter == 0);
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return(counter>= max);
}

public void addFront (E x){
    if(!isFull()) {
        if (head == 0) {
            head = deque.length-1;
            deque[head] = x;
        } else {
            deque[head--] = x;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Stack is full!");
}

public void addBack(E x){
    if(!isFull()) {
        if(tail == deque.length-1) {
            tail = 0;
            deque[tail] = x;
        } else {
            deque[tail++] = x;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Stack is full!");
}

public E removeFront(){
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        E ret = deque[head];
        deque[head++] = null;
        if(head >= deque.length) {
            head = 0;
        }
        counter--;
        return ret;
    }
    else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Stack is empty");
}

public E removeBack(){
    if (!isEmpty()) { 
        E ret = deque[tail]; 
        deque[tail--] = null;
        if(tail < 0) {
            tail = deque.length-1;
        }
        counter--;
        return ret;
        }
    else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Stack is empty");
}


public static void main (String [] args) {
Dequeues test = new Dequeues(20);
for (int i = 1; i <= test.deque.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        test.addBack(i);
    } else if(i % 2 == 1) {
        test.addFront(i);
    }
}

System.out.println("Use of removeFront and output of the values: ");
for (int i = 0; i < test.deque.length; i++) {       
    System.out.print(test.removeFront() + " ");
    }   
}}
```

Output is the following:

**Use of removeFront and output of the values: 
null 19 17 15 13 11 9 7 5 3 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just simply wrong used -- operator.
Right implementation of the addFront method should be:

```
public void addFront (E x){
    if(!isFull()) {
        if (head == 0) {
            head = deque.length-1;
            deque[head] = x;
        } else {
            deque[--head] = x;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Stack is full!");
}
```

So, the difference is here **deque[--head] = x**;

--head means reduce head value by one and then use it.

head-- means use value head and then reduce its value

Your situation was:

1. head = deque.length-1; head == 19
2. head != 0 and you go to the else statement. head value = 19. You used head-- and got again 19 and decremented it by one, but had to use --head.

Comment: Ah it works, thank you so much! I didn't noticed that.